# Automatic update-database in continuous deployment with Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Some weeks ago, I used the following steps to publish our developers' application to our testing Web site.

1. Get Latest Version (Recursive) in Solution Explorer.
2. Run Update-Database in Package Manager Console.
3. "Publish..."  in Solution Explorer.

This worked but we decided to automatize this with Continuos Integration in a build definition. I put the following MSBuild arguments into the build definition

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/p:DeployIisAppPath="MyProject-testing"
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=tfs.mydomain
/p:username=Administrator
/p:password=MYPassw!
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True
```

After some actions on the server tfs.mydomain, the executables and many other files of the application started appearing on the server automatically via the build definition. All except the database started being refreshed on the server automatically via the build definition. The application worked if there were no need to update database. But the updates are needed sometimes.

How can I modify the mentioned build definition to make the database up-to-date automatically what I did manually with Update-Database in Package Manager Console?

Thank you if you answer.

Comment: Try to check out the following sites. http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms243782.aspx Then try to create a workflow item that does the trick for the manual steps you did before.

Comment: Dear TimVK, I have read the pages on the links vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com and msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms243782.aspx because of your hint. I still don't understand how I can automatize update-database. Can you advise, where I can go further?

Comment: Try to add some new steps at the end of the workflow you are using that executes the database update scripts. I don't know how to do the database update exactly but that is something that can be found in a lot of places on the internet.

Comment: Have you fund the solution? I am in the same problem !

Comment: What did you see?! https://xkcd.com/979/